# Resizing a separately chained hash table with possibly duplicate keys

Tags: c, resize, hashtable

In a separately chained  implementation of a hash table written in C, I allow duplicate keys to be inserted and removed in LIFO order.

The condition to resize the table (double it's size) is when each list contains 10 items on average. The code looks something like this:

```
void maybeExpand(Hashtable* table)
{
    if (table->items < table->lists * 10)
        return;

    /* resize */
}
```

Note that I compare the ratio between the number of items to the **number of lists**, not the entire capacity of the hash table.

The problem is when the table consists of only duplicate keys and the the average number of items per list is bigger than 10. Resizing won't change the number of lists and the number of items, so the hash table would just keep being resized.

I wonder if allowing duplicate keys in a hash table is a good decision at all, and if so what to do in the case described above?

Comment: What's your rationale for resizing based on the number of lists rather than the entire table size?

Comment: The entire size of the table can be much bigger than the number of lists. If I rely on the size of the entire table, long lists can exist but not resized until many items are inserted.

Comment: You should consider the number of _keys_, not the number of data items. And I'd have each key having a queue of items, not duplicate keys with data that are handled strangely. Cleaner, IMVHO.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need a hashtable which allows multiple values per key or one which simply overwrites depends on the **situation**, if in doubt on how the hashtable will be used use some kind of switch to offer both.

The case where all entries are hashed to the same **hashbucket** is hard to predict. Choosing a *good* hashfunction is a good investment in any case; but in general you should only optimize for the average case, not the worst-case.

Comment: But the that case isn't the typical worst case that depends on the hash function. The hash function has to give identical hashes for equal keys anyway.

Comment: For identical keys absolutely.

Comment: But this isn't optimization related. Using that logic will probably result in a crash, because the rehashing won't change anything (rehashing equal keys will end up in the same bucket anyway) and hash table will keep expanding.

Comment: Well, you should set a maximum size anyway, eg you never want it to grow larger than eg 100MB so make it *not* rehash if already maximum size.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a waste of memory? (Expanding due to one list till hitting an upper bound)

Comment: The opposite: i am suggesting that your hashtable should only grow up to a certain point but not further.

Comment: But in that case the hashtable will grow to the maximum size, when perhaps there is only one list (containing duplicate keys).

Comment: Yes, that is why you have to set a maximum bucket number! If you dont set a maximum size, then the worst-case (all in one bucket) will consume too much memory.

Comment: I don't follow you. How would setting a maximum size not prevent a waste of memory? (If there's one bucket and table is at max size, isn't that called a waste of memory?)

Comment: It does not prevent that some memory is wasted, that is obviously impossible. It was in response of what you wrote: `"because the rehashing won't change anything (rehashing equal keys will end up in the same bucket anyway) and hash table will keep expanding"`. Setting a maximum number of hashbuckets only prevents that the hashtable continues to grow.